# SpringMVC: Can I specify a @ModelAttribute be populated only for specific controller methods?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

We have a couple of attributes that are common to 90% of the pages in our webapp.

I'd like to simply declare an `@ModelAttribute("userCredits")` on my controller to populate this common attribute.

However, for some pages I don't need this attribute. Can I avoid it being populated (it's modestly expensive to generate) in the one-off cases when it's not required?

I'm not a big fan of it being populated non-declaratively on every call, but I don't like the copy-paste addition of methods in each controller-handler to populate it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty confident there is no such support, which is also supported by observing the available annotations from the [`spring javadoc`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/package-frame.html)

Comment: Yeh, I was afraid I was out of luck, thanks for confirming your understanding of it.